# Audio recorder issue in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

First of all if something done wrong then forgive me, I am new in this platform.
Here is a good and working example of voice recorder for those who want.
I have created audio recorder feature in windows phone 8, everything works fine, but how do I get that audio extention,audio name and audio length in the sense of time?
for more details see my code:

```
private Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
    private byte[] buffer;                                  
    private MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();       
    private SoundEffectInstance soundInstance;              
    private bool soundIsPlaying = false;

    private BitmapImage blankImage;
    private BitmapImage microphoneImage;
    private BitmapImage speakerImage;

 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
        dt.Start();

        microphone.BufferReady += microphone_BufferReady;

        blankImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Img/blank.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        microphoneImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Img/microphone.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        speakerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Img/speaker.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));      
    }

 void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
        catch { }

        if (true == soundIsPlaying)
        {
            if (soundInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
            {
                // Audio has finished playing
                soundIsPlaying = false;

                // Update the UI to reflect that the 
                // sound has stopped playing
                SetButtonStates(true, true, false);
                UserHelp.Text = "press play\nor record";
                StatusImage.Source = blankImage;
            }
        }
    }

 void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        microphone.GetData(buffer);

        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    }

 private void recordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);


        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

        string audiofile = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        string audiosize = stream.Length.ToString();

        stream.SetLength(0);

        microphone.Start();

        SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
        UserHelp.Text = "record";
        StatusImage.Source = microphoneImage;
        btnAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

 private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            // Update the UI to reflect that
            // sound is playing
            SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
            UserHelp.Text = "play";
            StatusImage.Source = speakerImage;

            // Play the audio in a new thread so the UI can update.
            Thread soundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(playSound));
            soundThread.Start();
            btnAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }

 private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started)
        {
            // In RECORD mode, user clicked the 
            // stop button to end recording
            microphone.Stop();
        }
        else if (soundInstance.State == SoundState.Playing)
        {
            // In PLAY mode, user clicked the 
            // stop button to end playing back
            soundInstance.Stop();
        }

        SetButtonStates(true, true, false);
        UserHelp.Text = "ready";
        StatusImage.Source = blankImage;

        btnAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void playSound()
    {

        SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
        soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
        soundIsPlaying = true;
        soundInstance.Play();
    }

private void SetButtonStates(bool recordEnabled, bool playEnabled, bool stopEnabled)
    {
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = recordEnabled;
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = playEnabled;
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[2] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = stopEnabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed an example online and I noticed there are somethings missing from your code.

You should have these two methods also:

```
    public void WriteWavHeader(int sampleRate)
    {
        const int bitsPerSample = 16;
        const int bytesPerSample = bitsPerSample / 8;
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        // ChunkID Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form (0x52494646 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("RIFF"), 0, 4);

        // NOTE this will be filled in later
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(0), 0, 4);

        // Format Contains the letters "WAVE"(0x57415645 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("WAVE"), 0, 4);

        // Subchunk1ID Contains the letters "fmt " (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("fmt "), 0, 4);

        // Subchunk1Size 16 for PCM. This is the size of therest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(16), 0, 4);

        // AudioFormat PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization) Values other than 1 indicate some form of compression.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1), 0, 2);

        // NumChannels Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1), 0, 2);

        // SampleRate 8000, 44100, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate), 0, 4);

        // ByteRate = SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate * bytesPerSample), 0, 4);

        // BlockAlign NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 The number of bytes for one sample including all channels.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(bytesPerSample)), 0, 2);

        // BitsPerSample 8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(bitsPerSample)), 0, 2);

        // Subchunk2ID Contains the letters "data" (0x64617461 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("data"), 0, 4);

        // NOTE to be filled in later
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(0), 0, 4);
    }


    public void UpdateWavHeader()
    {
        if (!stream.CanSeek) throw new Exception("Can't seek stream to update wav header");

        var oldPos = stream.Position;

        // ChunkSize 36 + SubChunk2Size
        stream.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)stream.Length - 8), 0, 4);

        // Subchunk2Size == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 This is the number of bytes in the data.
        stream.Seek(40, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)stream.Length - 44), 0, 4);

        stream.Seek(oldPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
```

Then you should call `WriteWavHeader` on the `recordButton_Click` method, and `UpdateWavHeader` on the `stopButton_Click` after the `microphone.Stop()` call.

Because the microphone returns PCM data, what these headers do is turn the stream into a wav file, which you can later save in Isolated Storage, for example.

Below is the code to save the file to IsolatedStorage:

```
    private void SaveToIsolatedStorage(string filename)
    {
        // first, we grab the current apps isolated storage handle
        IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // we give our file a filename
        string strSaveName = filename;

        // if that file exists... 
        if (isf.FileExists(strSaveName))
        {
            // then delete it
            isf.DeleteFile(strSaveName);
        }

        // now we set up an isolated storage stream to point to store our data
        var isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strSaveName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());

        isfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);

        // ok, done with isolated storage... so close it
        isfStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: thnx Andre, can you give me one answer,how do I get file length in the sense of time and where is my filename in above code??thank you brother!!

Comment: I edited the answer and added code to save te file to isolatedStorage. You can give whatever name you want to your file. To find the duration of the file you can call the following method in the Stop handler:

`microphone.GetSampleDuration((int) stream.Length);`

Hoping your long isn't bigger than int.MaxValue.
Otherwise you can later load the file from IsolatedStorage as a MediaElement and there you see in Duration what you want.

If the answer is correct, please mark as correct ;) Thank you

Comment: Andre, thank you man!So can I user string filename = "demo.wav" ?thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The file is in wav, so you should use the .wav extension like you are doing already. Otherwise you'll be fine. ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: Andre, thnks!!is there any way to dynamically create new name?and my base64 is too long that visual studio is hanging, am I doing wrong in that method?

Comment: I never had the need to convert the stream to a base64string, but that can really create some big stuff :S
Regarding the name, you can use `string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".wav"`

Comment: thanks man, but I have to pass as base64 string, thats why I am converting, as per your view is it ok or not?

Comment: The code seems ok, but that can lead to a very big string, (also depending on the length of the record), so it is possible that Visual Studio hangs. Try with small recordings to see if it works